# Nativescript toggle class on Listview item

Tags: android, listview, native, nativescript

I have a quick question how can I toggle class on each list view item for example on tap. For example I have a code like below

```
<lv:RadListView id="ticketsList" items="{{ tickets }}">
    <lv:RadListView.itemTemplate>
        <StackLayout tap="showHide" class="item">
             <Label text="Hello" />
        </StackLayout>
    </lv:RadListView.itemTemplate>
</lv:RadListView>
```

And  I would like to show or hide element on tap with method "showHide", how can I do that.

Answer (score 1):

Use some custom property from your view model that will have a unique value for each item (e.g boolean `isItemVisible`). The technique is shown [here](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/4469#issuecomment-334079192)

Comment: Why would require` matter - using MVVM is not related to the JS/TS module imports. In plain JS you can create observable properties again using getter/setter and notifyPropertyChange https://github.com/telerik/nativescript-sample-cuteness/blob/master/nativescript-sample-cuteness/app/reddit-app-view-model.js#L60-L78 or directly by creating the property as a part of your Observable module and using `myViewModel.set` (which will internally call notifyPropertyChange) https://github.com/NativeScript/template-hello-world/blob/master/main-view-model.js#L18